# SAP WEBI - how to run two different query in same document

Tags: webi

I have 2 reports in the WEBI document, for every report, I need to use different SQL.

I tried to create another report with different SQL, but it changed the same query to the first report.

---

Second question :

I need to display some rows in different colors based on the amount. How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: do not put two questions in one, please. Always one by one https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one question it would be better to post them separately.

**1. Multiple Queries**

If you want a query with different SQL you need add another query from within the Query Panel.

[image]

By default it will be named "Query 2". If you are running a query for the first time WebI will put all of the Result Objects on your report. Otherwise you will need to manually add them to your report.

When I have multiple queries I always change the view at the bottom of the Available Objects pan to "Arranged by Query". Also, if you have the same object name in more than one query WebI will qualify it with the query name.

[image]

**2. Different Colors Based on Value**

You want to do what is referred to as **Conditional Formatting**. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOjpbZ3xqz4) is YouTube video on that. The link for that video came from the **SAP BusinessObjects Web Intelligence** link on the [Official Product Tutorials - SAP BusinessObjects BI Suite](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Official+Product+Tutorials+-+SAP+BusinessObjects+BI+Suite) website. I would recommend you spend some significant time reviewing the information there.

StackOverflow is very focused on code. Your questions are more about how to use Web Intelligence. Those types of question would be a better fit for the [BusinessObjects Board](https://bobj-board.org/).

Noel

Answer (score 0):

From the menu bar Analysis -> conditional -> new rule ..

You can create different rule (specify rule condition in it ) and for each rule you can give particular formatting option.

[Webi][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unXBw.png)

After selecting the column for which u need to apply the rule press FORMATTING Rules and check all the rules you need to apply .Hence you can achieve different color for different value (by assigning different rule )